# Type '(any Error)?' has no member 'success'

Tags: swift, function, case, xcode15

This is my create group function:

```
  webService.createGroup(url: apiUrl, requestBody: requestBody) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                print("Group created successfully:", response)
                completion(.success("Group created successfully"))
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error creating group:", error)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

```
 func createGroup(url: URL, requestBody: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestBody)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            do {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error creating group: \(error)")
                    completion(error)
                    return
                }

                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    print("Error: No HTTP response")
                    completion(WebService.NetworkError.invalidResponse)
                    return
                }

                print("HTTP Response Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

                guard (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                    print("Error: Unexpected HTTP response status code")
                    // Print response data for debugging purposes
                    if let data = data {
                        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Unable to convert data to string"
                        print("HTTP Response Data: \(responseString)")
                    }
                    completion(WebService.NetworkError.invalidResponse)
                    return
                }

                completion(nil)
            } catch {
                print("Error in createGroup: \(error)")
                completion(error)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

That was my web service function that I used to make the create group function in my grouplistviewmodel.

The error is: Type '(any Error)?' has no member 'success'

It is on line:

```
case .success(let response):
```

and

```
case .failure(let error):
```

Any help is much appreciated thank you!

Comment: Your `func createGroup(...)` only returns a `(Error?) -> Void`, not a results and an error.
So just use `if result == nil {...} else {...}` instead of your `switch result {...}`.

Comment: can u show me a code example please? I don't quite understand what you are sayibng. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is because your completion handler only returns a type `Error?` from your  `func createGroup(...)`,
and that, as the error says, does not have a `success`, it is either an `Error` or `nil`.

So try something like this:

```
webService.createGroup(url: apiUrl, requestBody: requestBody) { error in
    if error == nil {
        print("Group created successfully:")
    } else {
        print("Error creating group:", error)
    }
}
```

Typically you would have completion with something like `... completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error?>) -> Void)`, but it's up to you what you want to do.